# Pondering the purpose of TAILQ's tqe_prev not pointing to the previous node

Tags: c, linux, freebsd

In sys/queue.h there defines a data structure TAILQ. It is very popularly used throughout Linux kernel. Its definition is like this:

```
#define TAILQ_ENTRY(type)                                               \
struct {                                                                \
        struct type *tqe_next;  /* next element */                      \
        struct type **tqe_prev; /* address of previous next element */  \
}
```

I am a little baffled at this code: what is the advantage to have tqe_prev pointing the tqe_next of the previous node? If it was me, I would have tqe_prev directly pointing to the previous node, similar to tqe_next pointing to the next node.

One reason I'd think of, when we insert a node, we directly operate on the pointer to be updated, we do not need to go through its owning node first. But is that it? Any other advantages?

I am wondering how we can travel backwards of the queue? When we have a pointer to a node, since its tqe_prev does not point to the previous node, we have no way to go through the queue till the head. Or such backward travel is by design not supported by TAILQ?

Comment: Only the author would know for sure, but it's a reasonable assumption that this is a performance enhancement (eliminate the extra level of indirection to update the prior next). As for your second point, queues are often circular in nature, so it's not necessary to be able to go backwards.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, interesting. I didn't know this technique had any other users (I came up with it myself).

The reason to do things this way is that there may not be a "previous node": The first element does not have a predecessor, but it does have a pointer pointing to it.

This simplifies several operations. For example, if you want to delete a node given only a pointer to it, you can do this:

```
void delete(struct node *p) {
    *p->tqe_prev = p->tqe_next;
    if (p->tqe_next) {
        p->tqe_next->tqe_prev = p->tqe_prev;
    }
    free(p);
}
```

If you had a pointer to the preceding node, you'd have to write this:

```
void delete(struct node *p) {
    if (p->tqe_prev) {
        p->tqe_prev->tqe_next = p->tqe_next;
    } else {
        ???
    }
    if (p->tqe_next) {
        p->tqe_next->tqe_prev = p->tqe_prev;
    }
    free(p);
}
```

... but now you're stuck: You can't write the `???` part without knowing where the root of the list is.

Similar arguments apply to `insert` operations.

---

Backwards traversal is indeed not a priority for this kind of structure. But it can be done if must be (but only if you know for sure that you are not at the root, i.e. you know there actually is a previous node):

```
#include <stddef.h>

struct node *prev(struct node *p) {
    return (struct node *)((unsigned char *)p->tqe_prev - offsetof(struct node, tqe_next));
}
```

We know that `p->tqe_prev` is the address of a `.tqe_next` slot within a `struct node`. We cast this address to `(unsigned char *)` so we can do bytewise pointer arithmetic. We subtract the (byte) offset of `.tqe_next` within the `struct node` structure (`offsetof` macro courtesy of `<stddef.h>`). This gives us the address of the beginning of the `struct node` structure, which we finally cast to the right type.

Answer (score 0):

Linus answered the question in https://meta.slashdot.org/story/12/10/11/0030249/linus-torvalds-answers-your-questions.

The quote is as follows:

At the opposite end of the spectrum, I actually wish more people understood the really core low-level kind of coding. Not big, complex stuff like the lockless name lookup, but simply good use of pointers-to-pointers etc. For example, I've seen too many people who delete a singly-linked list entry by keeping track of the "prev" entry, and then to delete the entry, doing something like

if (prev)
prev->next = entry->next;
else
list_head = entry->next;

and whenever I see code like that, I just go "This person doesn't understand pointers". And it's sadly quite common.

People who understand pointers just use a "pointer to the entry pointer", and initialize that with the address of the list_head. And then as they traverse the list, they can remove the entry without using any conditionals, by just doing a "*pp = entry->next".